# Convert delimited string to hierarchical JSON with python

Tags: python

I have data in string: "1233/333/test1.js,1233/333/test2.js,2222/44/test2.js,ss.js"`

and want an output that will look like:

```
[{
     'title': '1233',
     'folder': true,
     'expanded': true,
     'children': [{
         'title': '333',
         'folder': true,
         'expanded': true,
         'children': [{
             'title': 'test1.js'
         }, {
             'title': 'test2.js'
         }]
     }]
 },
 {
     'title': '2222',
     'folder': true,
     'expanded': true,
     'children': [{
         'title': '44',
         'folder': true,
         'expanded': true,
         'children': [{
             'title': 'test2.js',
         }]
     }]
 }, 
 {
     'title': 'ss.js',
 }]
```

Any suggestions for this are appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and provide your code and efforts so far

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far, also looks like your 2nd string according to the output you need has to be `/333/` instead of `/33/`.

Comment: A good start would be `content = [item.split('/') for item in s.split(',')]` Can you think about how you can proceed from here?

Answer (score 0):

```
output = []
casesList = "1233/333/test1.js,1233/333/test2.js,2222/44/test2.js,ss.js".split(",")
for item in casesList:
    chain = item.split('/')
    currentNode = output
    for index,node in enumerate(chain):
        wantedNode = node
        lastNode = currentNode
        i = 0
        for x in range(i,len(currentNode)):
            i = x + 1
            if currentNode[x]["title"] == wantedNode:
                currentNode = currentNode[x]["children"]
                break
        if lastNode == currentNode:
            if '.' in wantedNode:
                currentNode.insert(i,{"title":wantedNode,"children":[]}) 
            else:
                currentNode.insert(i,{"title":wantedNode,"folder":True,"expanded":True,"children":[]}) 
            newNode = currentNode[i]
            currentNode = newNode["children"]

print(output)
```